# Guest access not allowed while integrating twitter via fabric in android application

Tags: android, twitter

Getting this error while using twitter sdk in my android application : Your app may not allow guest auth. Please talk to us regarding upgrading your consumer key.

Comment: plz post screenshot , if this is new integration it takes time to sync and up the fabric

Answer (score 0):

For any kind of access Twitter needs Authorised user now. 
Please check Authentication on all endpoints section https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public